# handling taskfactory task cancellation

Tags: vb.net, task-parallel-library, taskfactory

I am trying to have some control on the tasks I am creating using the taskfactory (parallel tasks) library in .net. My caller process creates two tasks that run two different methods accessible from two different referenced libraries.

```
 ' CALLER PROCESS
 Public ctsources As New CancellationTokenSource
 Public stsources As New CancellationTokenSource
 Public ct As CancellationToken = ctsources.Token
 Public st As CancellationToken = stsources.token   

 Dim cjob As Task = Task.Factory.StartNew(AddressOf consumer.mainModule.main, st)
 Dim pjob As Task = Task.Factory.StartNew(AddressOf producer.mainModule.Main, ct)

'BUTTON CLICK METHOD CANCELS TASKS
Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) 
  Handles Button2.Click
Try

    ctsources.Cancel()
    stsources.Cancel()


Catch ex As Exception

End Try
End Sub


' THIS IS IN THE TASK PROCESS METHODS CONSUMER.MAINMODULE.MAIN
 Public Shared stsources As New CancellationTokenSource
 Public Shared st As CancellationToken = stsources.Token
 If st.IsCancellationRequested Then
        disconnTime = DateTime.Now.ToString
        sendNetworkMessage("", disconnTime, "CONSUMER FORCIBLY DISCONNECTED")
        closeConnections()
 End If
```

And likewise the same for the other.I find the task still running and after I click the button I assumed the task would make the check IsCancellationRequested and then do the methods within the if then statement before cancelling. This allows me to have control of the task from the task process individually.

Comment: I think I just figured it out. I needed to just declare token source in caller and pass tokensource.token to the task process method and also make sure I accept it as an object in the method. I tried this and it seems to have worked. will update post soon.

Comment: I do have a related question though, is it possible to assign a task an ID